# Return error to client with Node.js domains

Tags: node.js, unhandled-exception, node.js-domains

I read that using domains is proper way of handling unhandled exceptions, but I don't know how to notify the end user for this error. I don't want this error to be unnoticed by the end user, I want to show them an error message.

My current code is like:

```
var domain = require('domain').create();

domain.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('Unhandled exception occured:\n', err.stack.toString());

  // Don't know how to access the response (nor request) object here so I can return error
  // res.json({error:'Error ocurred'});
});

domain.run(function() {
// Here is complete logic including definition of http server 
...
});
```

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: Did you try just attaching the response object to the per-request domain that you create?

Comment: @Vadim Yes, I use express and added express error handling but still some of the functionality is handled outside the express code and I don't think there is a way to solve this unless I wrap every router middleware with `try catch` block. @mscdex I don't quite understand you, do you mean I should create new domain for every request? I now have just one global domain and whole app run in that domain.